# Creating a LITE Version of App in XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im trying to create a LITE version of my app. Id like to use the preprocessor directives so I can use

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION
    // Code here
#endif
```

Heres what Ive done, so far
[image: Checklists]

I have duplicated the target and renamed to ChecklistsLite.
I added the Preprocessor Macro, LITE_VERSION
I changed the name and location of the ChecklistsLite-Info.plist file
I added some code to the ChecklistTableView.m file...

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION
    NSLog(@"Lite Version");
#elifdef FULL_VERSION
    NSLog(@"Full Version");
#else
    NSLog(@"No Version");
#endif
```

I built ChecklistsLite -> iPhone 4.3 Sim.
And when ran, it spits out "No Version", when it should say its "Lite Version".

Now why is it doing that?
Is there something that I am missing?
What is a scheme?
Why is the ChecklistsLite.app appear in red in the products list?

Comment: where are you defining/setting `LITE_VERSION` ? In the preprocessor macros, I see you call it `LITEVERSION`.

Comment: Just an answer for question three; its red because it has not yet been built.

Comment: I did change it to LITE_VERSION after the screenshot, but it still doesnt work :(

Comment: @Till so what is it building when I build it? The full app still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build option for 'Any architecture | Any SDK' is overwriting the build option set at the target-level. Xcode has some strange quirks in the build options dialog, in this case you'll need to add `LITEVERSION` to the preprocessor macros for the sub-option 'Any architecture | Any SDK', or just remove this sub-option.